# Erro de compilação em C++

Tags: c++, loop, syntax-error

Preciso fazer um *loop* (Repita-Até), mas está dando erro.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main (void){
    char deseja=1, valordomes1, valordomes2, valordomes3, totalFilia, totalEmpresa;
    do  
    {
        printf "valor do mes 1:";
        scanf >> ("valordomes1");
        printf "valor do mes 2:";
        scanf >> ("valordomes2;")
        printf "valordomes3:  ";
        scanf >> valordomes3;
        scanf >>  totalfilia := (valordomes1 + valordomes2 + valordomes3);
        printf "Valor total da filial:" totalfilia;
        printf "------------------------------------";
        totalempresa = (totalfilia);
        printf "Total do restaurante:" totalempresa;
        printf "se nao deseja calcular o proximo valor de vendas de outra filial digite o numero zero";

        while ( ! deseja=0 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seu código tem um número tão grande de erros de sintaxe, que pergunto: O que te levou a escrevê-lo desse jeito?

Comment: Gente acabei de sair do portugol, tenham paciencia kkk.. Tá dando esse erro: [Error] invalid operands of types 'int(const char*, ...)' and 'const char [12]' to binary 'operator>>'

Comment: E porque está tentando usar coisas o C se decidiu programar em C++? A primeira coisa que precisa decidir é que linguagem vai usar, esse talvez seja o motivo da confusão inicial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código tem bastante erros, e embora vá conseguir entregar o trabalho não parece que estará aprendendo a resolver o que surge e isto lhe trará problemas no futuro. Boa parte dos erros ocorrem por misturar C com C++. Mesmo escrito corretamente não deveria fazer isto. Como foi dito que deveria ser C++ é assim que demonstrarei.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int totalempresa = 0;
    while (1) {
        int valordomes1, valordomes2, valordomes3;
        cout << "valor do mes 1:";
        cin >> valordomes1;
        if (valordomes1 == 0) break;
        cout << endl << "valor do mes 2:";
        cin >> valordomes2;
        cout << endl << "valor do mes 3:";
        cin >> valordomes3;
        int totalfilia = valordomes1 + valordomes2 + valordomes3;
        cout << endl << "Valor total da filial: " << totalfilia << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------------" << endl;
        totalempresa += totalfilia;
        cout << "Total do restaurante: " << totalempresa << endl;
        cout << "se nao deseja calcular o proximo valor de vendas de outra filial digite o numero zero" << endl;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/EyazQ2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/GetDataLoop). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/GetDataLoop.cpp).

Tudo ponde está `printf` deve ser `cout`, esté é o correto para C++. E onde está `scanf` deve usar `cin`. E note bem os operadores de *stream* `<<` usado no `cout` já que você pega dados e manda para a saída, o tal do `cout`, e `>>` onde você manda a entrada que vem do `cin` para uma variável. Por isso tem uma lógica de quando usar cada um e onde.

Além disto eu coloquei `endl` nas saídas para decorar melhor e pular linhas onde for pertinente. Cada dado diferente deve ser um *stream* diferente. Em alguns casos usar um `\n´ dentro do próprio texto é bem aceitável e correto.

Se o critério de sair é digitar zero na primeira entrada então a lógica do laço está errada. Deveria ter um laço infinito e logo após alguém digitar o número do primeiro mês deveria verificar se é 0 e se for sair do laço.

Só uma variável deveria estar fora do laço que é a que calcula o total dos restaurantes, afinal esta variável não pode ser zerada em cada passagem do laço, as demais podem e uma até deve ser zerada para dar certo, e de qualquer forma declarar uma variável mais perto de onde ela é usada é o mais adequado, por isso passei todas as outras variáveis que sobraram (eliminei uma) para dentro do laço, e fazendo a inicialização. Se não inicializar pode pegar lixo e dar muita coisa errada.

Eliminei os parenteses desnecessários, mas principalmente eliminei o `:=` que é um operador inexistente em C++ (ou C).

Eu fiz soma da filial na empresa que é algo que me parece que era o que queria. Sem fazer a soma tem um erro de lógica.

Outro erro é que alguns lugares que estão como texto eram os nomes das variáveis, eu tirei as aspas. Como teve caso que fez certo não parece desconhecimento e sim falta de cuidado.

Não mudei os nomes das variáveis mas deveria adotar um padrão de estilo e dar nomes significativos completos, não coma letras, só tem desvantagens fazer isto. Então um `valorDoMes1` seria melhor, assim como `totalFilial`. Padronizar o estilo vale para outras coisas que eu percebi que não houve muita preocupação. Tinha algumas variáveis com nome errado e por isso o código não compilaria.

Programar é entender o que cada caractere do código faz, até o espaço em branco, não é jogar um monte de texto de qualquer jeito e esperar que funcione. Primeiro entenda o que está acontecendo em cada caractere para na próxima poder fazer sabendo do que se trata.

Comment: O criterio de sair era ao final do total da empresa o usuário escolher se queria continuar ou não. Eu estava em dúvida mesmo quanto aos parênteses, mas a questão dos nomes das váriaveis foi como a própria faculdade pediu, rs. Irei prestar mais atenção da próxima, valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Não é o que está no seu código, ele diz outra coisa. Se faculdade pediu para usar nomes de variáveis ruins eu sairia dela agora.

Answer (score 1):

Há um monte de erros. Esse daí é só o primeiro que o compilador achou. Em especial, o uso do `>>` é algo do C++ que usa `cout`. Já o `scanf` que é do C não usa `>>`. Aliás, esse erro que você teve tem cara de C++ e não de C. Devo lembrar que C e C++ são linguagens bem diferentes, e que você provavelmente deve estar tentando aprender o C, mas o seu código está mais perto do C++.

Primeiro, `scanf` e `printf` são funções. Como tal, você DEVE sempre usar parênteses nelas.

Segundo, tenha em mente que `printf` e `scanf` utilizam especificadores de formato tais como `%d`, `%c`, `%s` e `%f`. Embora haja muitas semelhanças, os especificadores do `printf` são diferentes dos que são usados no `scanf`. Veja os do `scanf` [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) e os do `printf` [aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).

Terceiro, que no C não é visto com bons olhos a prática de declarar todas as variáveis no começo, sendo preferido declará-las quando forem utilizadas. No entanto, esse detalhe é mais questão de estilo de escrita de código e não irá causar erros no programa.

Tentando alterar o seu programa rapidamente, acho que ele fica assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int deseja = 1, valordomes1, valordomes2, valordomes3, totalFilial, totalEmpresa = 0;
    do {
        printf("valor do mes 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &valordomes1);
        printf("valor do mes 2: ");
        scanf("%d", &valordomes2);
        printf("valor do mes 3: ");
        scanf("%d", &valordomes3);
        totalFilial = valordomes1 + valordomes2 + valordomes3;
        totalEmpresa += totalFilial;
        printf("Valor total da filial: %d\n", totalFilial);
        printf("------------------------------------n");
        printf("Total do restaurante: %d\n", totalEmpresa);
        printf("Se nao deseja calcular o proximo valor de vendas de outra filial digite o numero zero.\n");
        scanf("%c", &deseja)
    } while (deseja != '0');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Agora rodou, obrigado pelas dicas. E sim, o trabalho era pra ser feito em C++, eu que estava confundindo. valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Você está misturando C++ com C pelo jeito, segue abaixo o código correto do que eu entendi.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void){
    int deseja;
    float valordomes1, valordomes2, valordomes3, totalFilia, totalEmpresa;
    do{
            printf("valor do mes 1: ");
            scanf("%f", &valordomes1);
            printf("valor do mes 2: ");
            scanf("%f", &valordomes2);
            printf("valordomes3: ");
            scanf("%f", &valordomes3);
            totalFilia = (valordomes1 + valordomes2 + valordomes3);
            printf("Valor total da filial: %f \n", totalFilia);
            printf("------------------------------------\n");
            totalEmpresa = (totalFilia);
            printf("Total do restaurante: %f \n", totalEmpresa);
            printf("se nao deseja calcular o proximo valor de vendas de outra filial digite o numero zero\n");
            scanf("%d", deseja);
    }while(deseja == 1);
    return 0;
}
```